# What is the difference between CREATE INDEX AND CREATE UNIQUE INDEX?

Tags: android, sqlite

What is the difference between `CREATE INDEX` AND `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` in SQLite3 used in Android OS? How do indexes work in database? How are they related to columns in the table?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` isn't just an index : it adds the constraint that all records must have a different value for this column or combination of columns. If you try to insert a record whit the same combination, an error will be raised and prevent the insert (or update).

Use UNIQUE as soon as you're sure you'll have at most one record for some kind of key (user name for example).

EDIT : [Here's a link to the documentation of CREATE INDEX](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html), it describes in detail the syntax.

Comment: Few more details we help all.

Comment: Thanks. I don't if it will right to ask but if you could explain `How do indexes work in database? How are they related to columns in the table?`

Comment: An index is primarily a mean for a database engine to fast find records based on their column values. That's the link with the UNIQUE index : without an index, the engine couldn't find fast enough if a new record would conflict with the constraint. I suggest you google a little for indexes to learn how they work.